# Relative velocity of light beams

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, relativity

Assume two light beams moving in the same direction 
i want to use the  relativistic velocity transformation equation to find the relative velocity with each other,
Note : i let $C$=1

$V_{ab}$=$\frac{V_{a}-V_{b}}{1-V_{a}V_{b}}$
when i put $V_{a}$=$V_{b}$=1 the limit is $\frac{0}{0}$
though i expected to get $C$

Also used [that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=2958433016861a528d6221f5ac88eefd) website to get the limit told me
Limit Does not exit.

Comment: Do you know how to use L'Hôpital's rule? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule.

Comment: I think wolfran knows that rule , the problem is the limit depends on the path @CuriousOne

Comment: @MohamedOsama: That's true. It just occurred to me that there is more than one way to approach it (both mathematically and physically) and they are not equivalent. I think you should make that an answer!

Comment: But how physically the limit does not exit?!! the math formulation of Special relativity is true, i really do not know.@CuriousOne

Comment: @MohamedOsama: I am trying to come up with a good explanation... the physics is obvious: if we send out two light signals, the distance between the wave fronts will stay the same, so the "relative velocity" is zero. The question is how to capture that correctly with the formulas.

Comment: Why zero and not c? i;m waiting for your answer man.

Comment: @MohamedOsama: It's not c because phenomenologically the two wavefronts will never meet. You can do the experiment, if you like, but it should be obvious from a simple Gedankenexperiment: if we are sending out a 1s long flash of light, the front and the back will always be separated by 1s, even though both are moving at the speed of light.

Comment: One of your velocities is the velocity of beam A in the frame of beam B.  But beam B (like any light beam) has no frame.

Answer (score 2):

Special relativity does not tell you, that there are inertial systems moving along with a light ray. The formula for velocity addition is essentially a formula about transformation of a velocity in the frame of a moving observer.

It's just not the right question to ask, what an observer moving at $c$ would observe. Since there are none.

Comment: But how and Einstein said- or postulated- that laws of physics hold everywhere.

Comment: One can still ask how the limit has to be understood in the case of approaching c. I think that's actually the correct question: take two objects moving in parallel at the same velocity in any observer system. Take the limit of their velocity at the same time towards c. Does the formula give the right answer? I believe it does.

Comment: @ Mohamed: not everywhere - in every inertial system.
@ CuriousOne: this sounds as a valid question; but it's quite different from what Mostafa meant

Comment: Is the photon not inertial system?

Comment: @MohamedOsama: No, photons are not useful to define inertial systems. The mathematical question still stands and the answer is, as I suspected, L'Hôpital, one just has to come up with a justification for the correct limit.

Comment: @ CuriousOne I find it more elegant to see the fact that the limit is indeterminate as the perfect mathematical parallel to the fact that since the interval along a photon's path is zero, there would be no time to make an observation of relative velocity even if an observer could exist in a photon's frame.  This would mean there is no "correct limit".

Comment: @Ilja i heard that in General Relativity the laws of physics must be the same in non-inertial frame of reference too?

Comment: @DuncanHarris ...but obviously at any speed below $c$ it is possible; and it gives 0; how can a function, that is zero everywhere except at one point have no limit to that point?

Comment: @Ilja I think the problem is not with the function since alot of functions in math exhibit that behavior but the problem with our understanding of using that law as we wish.

Comment: no, I pose a purely mathematical question: there is a function x->y, where with x I mean the two velocities which I postulate to be equal. This function is constantly zero for $x<1$ and also for $x>1$. Then it has to have the limit at exaclty $1$, doesn't it?

Comment: The other topic: yes, General Relativity is a language for the description of arbitrary frames of reference, so that inertial systems are just a special case. But still no observer moving with $c$ is allowed. It's not not inertial, it's not a system

Comment: @MohamedOsama No, Einstein said the laws of physics hold in all reference frames. At the same time, relativity says that *there is no valid reference frame* moving at the speed of light relative to another. That is, physics doesn't even have the concept of how things might appear if moving at the speed of light.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity addition formula applies when there are two observers (say A and B) moving with respect to each other.  If C is some other object, we have three relevant velocities:  That of B as measured by A, that of C as measured by B, and that of C as measured by A.

But in your setup there is only one observer.  (A light beam is not an observer; it has no inertial frame).  So the velocity addition formula does not apply.

Comment: If we assumed the light beams were in different direction, why the formula will give us $C$--> an answer !! , but here it did not @WillO

Comment: @MohamedOsama: Sometimes the wrong formula gives the right answer. But you still shouldn't be surprised that the wrong formula doesn't *always* give the right answer.

Comment: @MohamedOsama: It does give the right answer, but you have to use $v_1=v_2$.

Comment: yes that's exacalty what i'm saying but Willo said it's a lucky answer by wrong formula @CuriousOne

Comment: @MohamedOsama: He is correct about that one, all I am saying is that you can "rescue" it with the physically necessary addition that $v_1=v_2$, because if you don't make that assumption, then the evaluation of the actual distance between the two will not be a constant, which doesn't make any physical sense.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is C.  Light travels at C, the speed of light, for any and all observer velocity.  That is your formula for relative velocity assumes time is a constant for all observers, but this assumption is invalid for your hypothetical.  For classical physics, time is nearly constant (or at least a good enough approximation), but it not EXACTLY true and fails as one approaches the speed of light.  For all observers approaching the speed of light, time slows down, and thus light continues to appear to be moving a speed C.

Funny story, this nearly exactly the question Einstein was trying to answer when he postulated and proposed special relativity.  In your hypothetical, (lets suppose each beam of light was able to "observe"), if a beam of light (or more accurately, the source of a beam of light) appeared to slow down, said beam of light would stop looking like a beam of light.  This is a contradiction of the nature of light; hence, Einstein concluded, through mathematics of course, that time must change for the moving observer (or source of light) so that light ALWAYS appears to be moving at C, his "Principle of Invariant Light Speed"

Comment: The comments says no frames moving with c